# Ant, java class output redirect

Tags: java, ant, console

I have problem. I use ant to redirect output from my java class, but there is problem, it`s reddirecting ALL output, not only "System.out.." (this is output that i want to reddirect). My class is getting remote objects and sometime it puts in console error messages. Can I deny those exceptions/errors so my class outputs only "System.out.."?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming your using the [Ant `java` Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) to run your class.  I'm also guessing you're redirecting output using the `output` or `outputProperty` attributes.

By default these options will also redirect standard error unless you explicitly redirect the error stream yourself.

So you can solve your problem by adding something like `errorProperty="propertytoignore"` to your task definition.  This will write the error messages to the property rather than your output file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding up to @Dave Webb's answer (and also assuming you're talking about the `java` task), you can add `error="null"` to the task:

```
<java classname="my.package.MyClass" output="${outfile}" error="null">
    <arg value="${arg1}"/>
    <arg value="${arg2}"/>
</java>
```

It works under Windows Eclipse Ant.